# Why can I not dynamically draw my table? How can I draw the table?

Tags: javascript, html, database, debugging, jquery

Readers,

Background:
I have an html page with a submit button on it. This button, when clicked goes to the servlet and fetches the first 10 rows of data from my database. I then get this data back to my javascript via an ajax call. That all works. I can see the data in json format in my javascript.

Problem: 
After the data is returned, it goes to a method called generate the table. But the table never shows on my html page. I tried to follow this demo [approach](http://theprofessionalspoint.blogspot.com/2012/07/how-to-create-dynamic-tables-in-html.html). How can I draw a table after this method is being called? The `<p></p>` approach in the demo didn't work in the link I provided either.

```
function createTable(result)
    {
        var length = result.jsonList.length;
        var tablecontents = "";
        console.log(length);
        tablecontents="<table>";
        for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            tablecontents += "<tr>"
            tablecontents += "<td>" + result.jsonList[i].Id + "</td>"
            tablecontents += "</tr>"
            console.log(result.jsonList[i].Id);
        }
        tablecontents="</table>";
        document.getElementById("tablespace").innerHTML = tablecontents;

    }
```

Okay, so the console.log part gives me the following output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9 
10
```

So I have the data. However, no database is being drawn on my htmlpage. Here is the relevant HTML code:

```
<body>

  <form id = "submitTable" method="post">


        <center><input id="getTable" type="button" value="Table"></center>  
        <div id="tablespace"></div>

 </form>
</body>
```

I point out the button calls the ajax. There is no need to show you my ajax call because that works. It calls my createTable function when it gets the data back from the servlet. I know it is working because I can print the unique database id's with the console.log. However, the

```
document.getElementById("tablespace").innerHTML = tablecontents
```

is not working? Stranger is that when I run and view source on chrome. I see no error with the html. So I don't know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I need this form. Would it help to place the div outside of that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
    tablecontents="</table>";
    document.getElementById("tablespace").innerHTML = tablecontents;
```

You set "tablecontents" to be *only* the `</table>` tag. Should be:

```
    tablecontents += "</table>"; // += not =
    document.getElementById("tablespace").innerHTML = tablecontents;
```

Comment: You answered this first, so I gave credit. Thank you so much. That was a subtle error. Devil is indeed in the details.

Answer (score 2):

`tablecontents+="</table>"` inplace of `tablecontents="</table>"`

Comment: I gave + rep for answering. Thank you!